# JAXB fails to marshal @XmlAttribute on fields in n-1 relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jaxb

I am using old school hibernate mapping with hbm.xml files. I have domains like this...

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement
public class Person {
  @XmlElement
  private Set<Vehicle> tags = new HashSet<Vehicle>(0);

  @XmlElement
  private Profile profile;

  @XmlAttribute  
  private String personName;//This is marshalled 
  //...  
}


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Vehicle {

  @XmlAttribute  
  private String vehicleName;//This is marshalled 
  //...
}


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Profile {

   @XmlAttribute
   private String profileName;//Why is this NOT marshalled?
  //...
}
```

When I marshall the Person object, why is the profileName not marshalled?

I have tried setting the hibernate mapping file to default field access with no effect. The only way I can get it to work is by placing the annotation on the getter. I was hoping to avoid this since I have some of my own reflection logic which inspects the fields only.

Comment: Are you marshalling instances of that classes or hibernate proxies? (Look at a debugger or sysout instance.getClass().getName())

Comment: hmmm, Profile is a proxy. Oh dear. So what options do I have since Im not going to eager load every object graph? I guess field annotations are out. Still not clear why the annotation on the getter would work.

Comment: Fields and methods behave differently when it comes to inheritance (a Proxy is a subclass of the proxied class). Fields can not be overriden, so the proxy can not delegate the "calls" to them to the delegate. Basically you have two sets of fields, one in the proxy and one in the delegate and these are not in sync. So your option would be to change your reflection code to use getters/setters.

Comment: Bad news for me, but at least I understand the problem. Thanks.